# Just print the array in the console

Tags: c, arrays

I have a strange request, but I just need to output the array. I wrote the code, but my teacher asked me to also print the input array. I don't understand how to implement this correctly in my case.
Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    float a[15], q = 1.5;
    a[0] = 2.0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
        a[i] = a[i - 1] * q;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        printf("%i  %4.2f\n", i, a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you currently have? Doesn't it output  the array already?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code *assuming* it is implementing what it should.

Comment: "My teacher asked me to also print the input array", theres only one array here.  I suspect your misunderstanding the assignment.

Comment: I'd guess your teacher means print out the array before it's modified, then again after it's modified.. but if you don't know you need to ask. Since it's not initialized (except for `a[0]`), you'll just see a bunch of random data ... maybe that's the point.